# Errno 13 Permission denied when python script called by php

Tags: php, python, system, permission-denied

I am trying to open a file, which is present on network through python script. This is working fine when running python script through my windows command prompt:

```
python script.py \\jocker\linux\


import sys

filename =  sys.argv[1]+"notes\\details.txt"
try:
    f= open(filename,"r")
    for line in f:
        print (line)
except Exception as e:
    print (str(e))
```

But problem occurs when I calling this python file through php script,

```
<?php
$file = "\\\\jocker\linux\\";
$com='python ./script.py '.$file ;
$ret= system($com,$outp);


 [Errno 13] Permission denied. \\\\jocker\\linux\\notes\\details.txt
```

I am not getting: is there any permission issues or any problem with path?

Comment: @abarnert when I run python script through Windows, it is accessing file correctly. This file is mount on the NFS server.  I tried os.path.join also, but showing same error.

Comment: For checking it, I edited python script with `os.path.join('\\\joker','linux','notes','details.txt') ` Then `print filename ` gives  correct path `\\jocker\linux\notes\details.txt` But while  accessing the file, error is same: `permission denied \\\\jocker\\linux\\notes\\details.txt `

Comment: Same python script running via windows prompt giving correct output. Even I am able to open file directly through terminal. But my php, python code is deployed on window's localhost and then it gives error. @abarnet are you sure this is only filepath problem?

Comment: @abarnert `\\\\jocker\\linux\\notes\\details.txt ` and `\\jocker\linux\notes\details.txt ` both file paths are opening in browser. Please help in figuring out what may be possible errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By looking your path, i am thinking you are using linux.. When we run a program with php, the read/write permissions comes as we have for php user. Please check which use the php program using, and is that user has permissions on that folder

Comment: @PraveenMyakala Thanks for reply. python script and php program both have same user. `import getpass
username=getpass.getuser()
print(username)` And I am able to open file directly in browser `\\\\jocker\\linux\\notes\\details.txt `

Comment: Please try like this once os.path.join('\\joker','linux','notes','details.txt')

Comment: @PraveenMyakala I tried this also. It seems not a problem of syntax. Problem is how to access local server shared file/folder through localhost apache server..How to pass credentials to this shared folder through python or php or any language?